# Pivot data from JSON object

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a base table where i store records per team in a json object;

```
[
 {
   "Id": 1,
   "date": "01-01-2022",
   "Group": "A",
   "Description": "test 1"
 },
 {
   "Id": 2,
   "date": "01-01-2022",
   "Group": "B",
   "Description": "test 2"
 },
 {
   "Id": 3,
   "date": "08-01-2022",
   "Group": "B",
   "Description": "test 3"
 },
 {
   "Id": 4,
   "date": "16-01-2022",
   "Group": "A",
   "Description": "test 4"
 },
 {
   "Id": 5,
   "date": "16-01-2022",
   "Group": "C",
   "Description": "test 5"
 }
]
```

Now for reporting purpose i need to pivot the table like:

| Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | test 1 | test 2 | - |
| 08-01-2022 | - | test 3 | - |
| 16-01-2022 | test 4 | - | test 5 |

I really dont know how to perform such action with PHP or Javascript.. Tried with for each loops but i only got the date as a unique value.

btw; for empty rows to show "-" is fine.

Comment: Please show what you tried and what the result was, then we have a starting point. We prefer not to need to go over the ground you've alread trodden, as it usually saves time.

Comment: Are you using laravel? The A,B,C groups are fixed or dynamic? I mean, can be D,E,F...?

Comment: @jack these are dynamic